# Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException Trait not found in Laravel project

Tags: php, laravel

I have create a new trait within my Laravel project, but it doesn't work.

First I have created a folder called `App\Traits` and my trait filename is `UploadTrait.php`.

Content:

```
<?

namespace App\Traits;

use Illuminate\Support\Str;
use Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;

trait UploadTrait
{
    public function uploadOne(UploadedFile $uploadedFile, $folder = null, $disk = 'public', $filename = null)
    {
        $name = !is_null($filename) ? $filename : Str::random(25);

        $file = $uploadedFile->storeAs($folder, $name.'.'.$uploadedFile->getClientOriginalExtension(), $disk);

        return $file;
    }
}
```

I try to use this trait in my controller as follows:

```
use App\Traits\UploadTrait;

class ProfileController extends Controller
{
    use UploadTrait;

    ...
```

I'm getting the error message:

> Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException Trait
>
> 'App\Traits\UploadTrait' not found

Can anyone help me to get this solve?

Comment: Have you tried running `composer dump-autoload -o` on the CLI?

Comment: yes i did but still not works

Comment: The `<?` instead of `<?php` sticks out to me.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `<?`, always use `<?php`.

a php linter will also avoid this issue

So always use `<?php` !!!